# Convert for loop into Java 8 Stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I need to convert these code into Java 8 Stream I tried it using the given below code written by me but still I haven't got what I wanted.

```
//contractList is list of Contract class
//contract.getProgramId() returns String
//contract.getEnrollmentID() returns String
//'usage = CommonUtils.getUsageType()' is other service to call which returns String
//enroll and usage are String type
//enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson is json object '{"enroll": value, "usage": value}'
//usages is List<JSONObject> where enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson need to add

for (Contract contract : contractList) {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(contract.getProgramId())) {
        enroll = contract.getEnrollmentID();
        usage = CommonUtils.getUsageType(envProperty, contract.getProgramId());
        if (!(StringUtils.isEmpty(enroll) || StringUtils.isEmpty(usage))) {
            enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson.put("enroll", enroll);
            enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson.put("usage", usage);
            usages.add(enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson);
        }
    }
}
```

This is till now what I have got:

```
contractList.stream()
    .filter(contract -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(contract) &&
            !StringUtils.isEmpty(contract.getProgramId()))

    .collect(Collectors.to);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Any particular reason you need to use streams? The for-loop looks fine to me.

Comment: first your  code having errors that `usages` always adding the same `JSONObject` instance.

Comment: What’s the point of `StringUtils.isEmpty(contract)`? `contract` is not a `String`. Besides that, you should consider not using 3rd party libraries for every trivial thing, especially, if the only “benefit” of these methods is to get a questionable `null` handling.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how a stream based version of your code might look like (add static imports as needed):

```
List<JSONObject> usages = contractList.stream()
    .filter(c -> isNotEmpty(c.getProgramId()))
    .map(c -> new SimpleEntry<>(c.getEnrollmentID(), getUsageType(envProperty, c.getProgramId())))
    .filter(e -> isNotEmpty(e.getKey()) && isNotEmpty(e.getValue())))
    .map(e -> {
        enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson.put("enroll", e.getKey());
        enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson.put("usage", e.getValue());
        return enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson; })
    .collect(toList());
```

I took the liberty of using `isNotEmpty` from Apache Commons as given this option `!isEmpty` looks terrible. I am (ab)using `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` to hold a pair of values. If you feel `getKey`, `getValue` make the code less readable, you can introduce a class to hold these 2 variables. E.g.:

```
class EnrollUsage {
    String enroll, usage;
}
```

You may also prefer to define a method:

```
JSONObject withEnrollAndUsage(JSONObject json, String enroll, String usage) {
    json.put("enroll", enroll);
    json.put("usage", usage);
    return json;
}
```

and in the above use instead:

```
.map(e -> withEnrollAndUsage(enrollNoWithUsageTypeJson, e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
```

Keep in mind that you never really *"need"* to convert code to use streams. There are cases where using streams, albeit intellectually satisfying, actually complicates your code. Exercise your best judgement in this case.

Comment: Thanks Manos, 
Your solution works...
I want to convert these code into java8 for my best practice to use Java8 streams.

Comment: How is this best practice?  They are equally complex to me.